# •Request filtering is configured for the Web server and the file extension for this request is explicitly denied

Tags: asp.net

HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found

The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.

I am using Visual studio 2013 web express. When I running Defalt.aspx its running fine but when i run materpage.master it throw me this error. I tried a lots of solution and its still not working( i tried to change the web.conf). Anyone know what can I do for this issues>?

code for web.conf

```
<configuration>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=XE;Password=1234;User ID=System"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    <add name="databaseString" connectionString="Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Data Source=XE;Persist Security Info=True;Password=1234;User ID=system"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    <add name="SOConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Data Source=XE;Persist Security Info=True;Password=1234;User ID=so"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />

</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't directly access [master pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). You access a content page (.aspx) that references a master page.

Comment: then how can I do it? coz whenever I debug my program, its always prompt DEFAULT.aspx instead of masterpage.

Comment: @LstPatrick How can you do *what*? Access a master page directly? You can't do that. You have to access a content page that references a master page. There'd be no reason to directly access a master page.

Comment: for example like, my VS run page1.aspx by default, can I change and make it run page2.aspx?

Comment: @LstPatrick Yes, you can go into the project configuration and change the start page. That has nothing too do with master pages.

Comment: @LstPatrick Right click the Project, click Properties, go to the Web tab, and set the Start Action to whatever you want.